# R - set list element names from strings they contain using tidyverse

Tags: r

Let's say you have a list like this one:

```
cityhoods <- list("Zagreb/Donji Grad",
               "Berlin/Mitte",
               "Warsaw/Stare Miasto")
```

Now if I want the list elements to have names "Zagreb", "Berlin" and "Warsaw", I could of course do this:

```
names(cityhoods) <- c("Zagreb", "Berlin", "Warsaw")
```

However, I have a very large number of list elements, not just 3 like in this example, and I am doing all the previous operations within a pipeline. I was wondering what would be a pipe-friendly way to pull the city name from the list element and then assign it as the name of the list element.

**EDIT**

There seems to be a lot of misunderstanding of my question, so I would like to try to better clarify what conditions does the answer need to satisfy:

1. It is pipe-friendly, i.e., the solution can be used within a pipeline `%>%` without breaking it.
2. It extracts the part of the city/neighbourhood string before the slash, e.g., it extracts `Berlin` from `Berlin/Mitte`.
3. It assigns these extracted strings as names of the list elements.

This is all mentioned in the original question but I thought if I segment it out like this it will be clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a function that should do what you want.

```r
name_list <- function(x) {
  
  setNames(x, sub('/.*', '', x))
}

cityhoods %>% name_list
# $Zagreb
# [1] "Zagreb/Donji Grad"
# 
# $Berlin
# [1] "Berlin/Mitte"
# 
# $Warsaw
# [1] "Warsaw/Stare Miasto"
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do:

```
add_names <- function(x) {
  names(x) <- gsub("/.*", "", x)
  x
}

cityhoods %>% add_names()
```

Comment: No, I am looking for a way to set these extracted strings as names of list elements within a pipe

Comment: Updated answer. I wrapped same instructions in function

Answer (score -1):

```r
library(tidyverse)

cityhoods <- list("Zagreb/Donji Grad",
                  "Berlin/Mitte",
                  "Warsaw/Stare Miasto")

cityhoods %>%  
  str_extract(".*(?=/)")

#> [1] "Zagreb" "Berlin" "Warsaw"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: But I also need to assign the names to the list elements... Not just pull them